# react-dropzone is not working on custom react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-dropzone

I have a react app with custom webpack config (bundle optimizers and style loaders, nothing fancy). react-dropzone is working on my sandbox. But the same code is not working on my custom react app

Code is too long 
https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-surf-vjdno

I have some thoughts in my mind about webpack configuration, because it is working on sandbox

**UPDATE**

I found that it is working inside normal components, its not working inside conditional rendering

Anyone know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It is related to event bubbling, I enabled event bubbling for the parent component and it worked!!